# TFS 2018 associating work item with commit without pull request

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

we are using git in our on-premises TFS 2018 <s>RC2</s> RTW

when we checkin our code we assiciate a work item by adding a hash and a number e.g. #8635

[image]

It is written in the [docs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/03/02/linking-work-items-to-git-branches-commits-and-pull-requests/) that this should work with pull-requests. But in our case we do not neccessarly need pull-requests.

**Is it possible to link commits with work items without pull-requests?**

related:

- [VSTS: How to get all linked work items since last successful release to production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36599939/vsts-how-to-get-all-linked-work-items-since-last-successful-release-to-producti)
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/03/02/linking-work-items-to-git-branches-commits-and-pull-requests/

**Update:**

I just tested this on a different git project on the same team project.

Guess what: It's working as expected. Strange there needs to be something with this git project...

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, this link works as soon as it is pushed to the TFS-repo. Your work item should have a link to the commit.

Comment: @FabianH.this is exactly what we would have expected. But this is not the case...

Comment: Have you tried this from Visual Studio? I see in your screen shot, you are doing this at the command line and I'm wondering if VS is doing something in the background which makes it work.

Comment: Yes. We also trief committing over Visual Studio. It does Not make a difference.

Comment: So if you go to the links tab of work item 8635 you don't see any associated commits?

Comment: @PeroP. correct. There are no associated commits.

Comment: Interesting: i tried this on a different git project within the same team project and it is working... I updated the question with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `http://<yourTFSinstance>/tfs/<TeamProjectCollection>/<TeamProject>/_admin/_versioncontrol`, then select the repo in question, and switch to the *Options* tab. Make sure the appropriate checkmark is ON:

[image]

Comment: You are a live-saver! In that very moment we also found this: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/170644/commit-not-associated-with-work-item.html

Answer (score 0):

I've tested on my TFS 2018 RTM, and got correct behavior. You could try to upgrade your TFS 2018 RC2 to RTM version first.

And make sure after `git commit -m` command, you also `git push` the commit.

[image]

Comment: Believe me, we are doing exactly what you wrote. Interestingly, as i stated out, this behaviour is only on one git repo. Our Version 16.122.27102.1 which is Team Foundation Server 2018 RTW. We observed this behavior as well as we had TFS 2017.

Comment: Any clue why it is NOT working on a specific/single repo?

Comment: @Daniel Have you checked Yan's suggestion?